# Verificar retorno async vazia Fluttter

Tags: flutter, dart

Como posso verificar se um retorno `async` de um determinado `sqlite` está vazio?

Preciso verificar se o "resultReceita" esta null antes de exibi-lo no widget.

tentei com um if porém, não obtive sucesso. Este código funciona perfeitamente, porém quando o usuário instala pela primeira vez ele ainda não fez lançamentos, dessa forma, retorna um erro "null" no futurebuilder.

Meu código:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //FUTURE BUILDER PARA EXIBIR SALDO CONTAS
    Future<int> _query() async {
      var db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
      var resultReceita = await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE tipo = "R"');
      var resultDespesa = await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE tipo = "D"');

      if (resultReceita == null) {
        print("Esta vazio");
      } else {
        print("Não vazio");
      }

      print('resultado $resultReceita');
      print('teste2 $resultDespesa[0]');

      return resultReceita[0]["SUM(valor)"] - resultDespesa[0]["SUM(valor)"];
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque o seu código formatado exatamente como você está usando (esse aí que você postou nem compilaria, estão faltando chaves {}), e também coloque o stacktrace do erro que está ocorrendo.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo a estrutura do teu código, tente usar o `.isEmpty`

```
if (resultReceita.isEmpty)
  print("Esta vazio");
else
  print("Não vazio");
```

**Explicação**

A sua consulta do banco pode não estar retornando nenhum registro, mas o objeto `resultReceita` foi criado, sendo assim diferente de `NULL`, por isso não funcionava a sua validação.
No seu caso é retornada uma `List<T>` sem registro algum, então o correto é validar se a lista está vazia ou não.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//FUTURE BUILDER PARA EXIBIR SALDO CONTAS
Future<int> _query() async {
  var db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
  var resultReceita = await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE tipo = "R"');
  var resultDespesa = await db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE tipo = "D"');

  if (resultReceita.isEmpty)
    print("Esta vazio");
  else
    print("Não vazio");

  print('resultado $resultReceita');
  print('teste2 $resultDespesa[0]');

  return resultReceita[0]["SUM(valor)"] - resultDespesa[0]["SUM(valor)"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar a palavra chave `await` , recomendo que utilize no Future da query ao Banco de Dados o seguinte:

```
db.rawQuery('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM lancamentos WHERE tipo = "R"').then((resultReceita) {
   if (resultReceita.isEmpty)
     debugPrint("Esta vazio");
   else
     debugPrint("Não vazio");

}).catchError((error) {
     debugPrint("ERRO");
     debugPrint(error.toString());
})
```

Assim tu consegue entender exatamente o que está acontecendo na query, é possível que esteja ocorrendo um Erro pelo valor ser Null (catchError) , ao invés de um retorno normal (then).

Depois de debugar e entender o problema, tu pode utilizar o `await`, mas agora sabendo que o `var resultReceita` pode estar recebendo um objeto do tipo `Error` ou `Exception`, ao invés de um `Result` do banco de dados. Rodar o método `.isEmpty()` em um `Error` ou `Exception` gerará um erro e consequentemente não acessará as linhas seguintes de código.

Existem outras abordagens possíveis para capturar o erro, como envolver seu código atual em um Try & Catch, recomendo que dê uma lida sobre futures para entender melhor em: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Ps: Utilize o `debugPrint` ao invés do `print`, caso vá para produção ele não afetará a performance do usuário.

Comment: Acho desnecessário o uso do then neste caso. Ele está presente no dart apenas por retrocompatibilidade. É bem mais legível o uso de async/await para futures e try/catch captura de erros.

Comment: Não sabia disso, retrocompatibilidade com o que exatamente?
Pensei nessa solução por entender que fica mais fácil de se entender que está ocorrendo um error, depois como disse na resposta recomendei o artigo que indica o Try & Catch igual você está falando.